# How to filter and mail a part of my table from access into the body of my email

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having some problems with my Access d-Base. I will try to explain what I want to achieve:

I have a continuous form based on a query with a lot of records. Users have to scan these records and If needed send a selection of these records to the concerning customer. Therefore I have used a textbox in my form combined with the following query column:

```
Expr1: (IIf([Forms]![frm_POOpenOrdersPerVendor]![partnrFilter] Is Null,True,[po_partnr]=[Forms]![frm_POOpenOrdersPerVendor]![partnrFilter]))
```

And criteria is: <>False

This works perfect in my form. After my filter is set I want to e-mail the results in the body of my email (Outlook). To do this I use:

```
Option Compare Database

Public Sub Export_PO()

 On Error GoTo EH
 'Recordset variables
 Dim db As Database
 Dim rstOpenPurchaseOrders As Recordset
 Dim strSQL As String
 Dim strSubject As String
 Dim strBody As String
 Dim strAddresses As String
 Set db = CurrentDb()
 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qry_POOpenOrdersPerVendor;"
 Set rstOpenPurchaseOrders = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
 If Not rstOpenPurchaseOrders.EOF Then
 strBody = "blah blah blah" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
 strBody = strBody & "Partnumber" & " | " & "Vendor Partnumber" & " | " & "Promise Date" & vbCrLf
 strBody = strBody & "===========================================================" & vbCrLf
 rstOpenPurchaseOrders.MoveFirst
 Do While Not rstOpenPurchaseOrders.EOF
  strBody = strBody & rstOpenPurchaseOrders![po_partnr] & Chr(9) & rstOpenPurchaseOrders![po_vendor_part] & Chr(9) & rstOpenPurchaseOrders![po_prom_date] & vbCrLf
                      rstOpenPurchaseOrders.MoveNext
          Loop
      End If
      strSubject = "Here's my report!"
      strAddresses = "look.look@nmhg.com"
      DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , acFormatTXT, asAdresses, , , strSubject, strBody, True
      Exit Sub
EH:
     MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
     Exit Sub
 End Sub
```

Separately my codes work fine (both). If I want to combine them I get the error "3061 Too few parameters. Expected 1."

Anybody?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your Query qry_POOpenOrdersPerVendor - required one argument to be passed either via a Form or just by prompting for a value. In VBA if you wish to use a precompiled query that expects a parameter you will bump into this error. So you need to use the main Query to be used in the VBA NOT the name of the Query.